# Why is NaN === NaN false?

Tags: javascript, nan

Why does `NaN === NaN` return `false`  in Javascript?

```
> undefined === undefined
true
> NaN === NaN
false
> a = NaN
NaN
> a === a
false
```

On the [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) I see this:

> ### Testing against NaN
>
> Equality operator (`==` and `===`) cannot be used to test a value against `NaN`. Use `isNaN` instead.

Is there any reference that answers to the question? It would be welcome.

Comment: Because *Not a Number* is not a number, and is not equal to anything, including *Not a Number*.

Comment: @Joren - This isn't JS specific.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: take a look at this great video ;-)
https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: @Joren: All languages do this.

Comment: NaN is the only number that isNaN :-)  To check if something is NaN, test ``isNaN(value) && typeof value=='number'``

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Strict answer**: Because the JS spec [says so](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6):

> - If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>   - If x is NaN, return false.
>   - If y is NaN, return false.

---

**Useful answer**: The IEEE 754 spec for floating-point numbers (which is used by all languages for floating-point) says that NaNs are never equal.

Comment: Also, it's part of the axioms that define natural numbers. Check out the second bullet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation

Comment: @Loupax How does that relate? NaN is not a natural number. It's not a number? Is there a joke here I'm not getting?

Comment: @GrantGryczan I don't even remember what I had in mind back then. Now I just think of this as "Just because the NaNs beside the equality operator are not numbers, it doesn't mean they are the same non number" and just leave it at that

Comment: JavaScript automatic type conversion convert `NaN` into number, so checking if a number is not a number will always b `false`. and `NaN !== NaN` will be true.

Answer (score 14):

This behaviour is specified by the [IEEE-754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) (which the JavaScript spec follows in this respect).

For an extended discussion, see [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Answer (score 2):

Although either side of `NaN===NaN` contains the same value and their type is `Number` but they are not same. According to ECMA-262, either side of `==` or `===` contains `NaN` then it will result false value.

you may find a details rules in here-

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3