# Javascript Float + Float = String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

When I am running this, it returns `NaN`. If I do not parseFloat, I'm getting 2 strings added. What am I missing? I would say that my result should always be a float?

```
function calculate(i) {
    var result = 0.0;
    $j(".t" + i + " input").each(function () {
        var number = $j(this).val();
        number = number.replace(",", ".");

        if (parseFloat(number) != NaN) {
            result = parseFloat(result);
            number = parseFloat(number);
            result += number;
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: No value equals `NaN`. Ever.

Comment: Adding the HTML may help (and also the values from the input fields).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not validating *not a number* correctly. To check if a number is `NaN` use the `isNaN` function:

```
if (!isNaN(parseFloat(number))) { ... }
```

Note that `NaN === NaN` returns `false` always.

You can read more about this here: [Why is NaN === NaN false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19955898/1420197)

Here is the complete code:

```
function calculate(i) {
    var result = 0;
    $j(".t" + i + " input").each(function () {
        var number = $j(this).val();
        number = parseFloat(number.replace(",", "."));

        if (isNaN(number)) {
            return;
        }
        result += number;
    });
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo `(!isNanN(` Should be `(!isNaN(` right?

Comment: Very welcome :) Simple mistake. I knew something looked out of place, I had to look twice to notice it.

Comment: Working now. Thank you very much! :) Answer accepted.